# Pattern for observer and one subject

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

If I only have a single observer observing a single subject at all time, do I still use the observer pattern?

Or is there another pattern that will better suit the above scenario?

Comment: Try delegation pattern.

Comment: Does this single subject have many properties to observe or just one?

Comment: only one property to observe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observer pattern still suits. But patterns are not set in stone, you can simplify it a bit if you don't need a collection of observers: implement the observer-->subject association as 1:1

Comment: Do you think there's still a need for abstract class (observer and subject)? Since the purpose of abstract class to me, is to allow extension of more observers/subjects.

Comment: I'd still create interfaces to keep the classes as loosely coupled as possible but abstract classes should not be necessary in your case.